# Hiding personal info from WhoIs

Tags: privacy, whois

Is there a way to hide it?

**WhoIs Info for stackoverflow.com**

Registrant:

Jeff Atwood
410 Clayton Ave
El Cerrito, California 94530,
United States
Registered through: GoDaddy.com, Inc. (http://www.godaddy.com)
Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.COM
Created on: 26-Dec-03
Expires on: 26-Dec-14
Last Updated on: 13-Apr-08

Comment: Basically, you would want to deal with a registrar outside of the following areas: US, Canada, EU, Australia, UK. That would be the start. I've heard about one Japan-based registrar but right now can't find its name.

Comment: There were one registrar in Turkey as well.

Answer (score 6):

Most of these companies will give out your hidden info at the first request. At least enom does so, I've read somewhere they give out info to any request that mentions the word "infringement". I've also heard there are sites that watch and gather whois updates, inclusive the very first registration data before whois privacy has been activated. They sell then this info to whoever pays.

If you want privacy use fake info. But then you are traceable via payment operations.

So the answer to your question, in the long run that will not be possible.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see, stackoverflow.com is registed in GoDaddy. For 2 bucks extra they offer to protect your personal info by DomainsByProxy.com. The registrant, administrative and technical contacts show their info:

```
Registrant:
   Domains by Proxy, Inc.
   DomainsByProxy.com
   15111 N. Hayden Rd., Ste 160, PMB 353
   Scottsdale, Arizona 85260
   United States
```

Answer (score 2):

Some companies allow you to keep your information private. At least bluehost does. Look at this info: http://helpdesk.bluehost.com/kb/index.php?x=&mod_id=2&id=146.

In their case they call it domain privacy, and you could transfer to their registrar in case you need to do it with a domain you already registered.

Comment: and do they charge additional for that privacy?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can do it or how to do it. But I do know that I have my domain through Dreamhost, and they provide a way for me. So when I do WhiIs on my domain, I get this:

> geekjuggler.net Private Registrant
>   geekjuggler.net@proxy.dreamhost.com
>   DreamHost Web Hosting
>   417 Associated Rd #324
>   Brea, CA 92821
>   US
>   +1.2139471032
>
> Record created on 2007-06-24 14:29:55.
>   Record expires on 2009-06-24 14:29:55.